# How can I draw the current keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I want to draw an ascii version of the current keyboard layout. Something like this, but with all keys:

```
  +---------------------------------------+
  | q | w | e | r | t | y | u | i | o | p |
  | a | s | d | f | g | h | j | k | l |   |
  | z | x | c | v | b | n | m |           |
  +---------------------------------------+
```

Any idea on how to do that? If you know of an app like that, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question worth asking, but not here I think...

Comment: you can use `zathura <(xkbprint :0 -o - | ps2pdf -)`. it is not ascii though.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the keyboard layout first and then based on the layout type print the keyboard. Think you should create a map of the layout types and the printing yourself.

Get keyboard:
    cat /etc/default/keyboard

Will echo the following and search for XKBLAYOUT.

```
# If you change any of the following variables and X is configured to
# use this file, then the changes will become visible to X only if udev
# is restarted.  You may need to reboot the system.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
```